# How to access and update nested object array in React

Tags: reactjs

The object i have is

```js
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([
    {
      title: "folder2",
      id: 1,
      child: [
        {
          title: "folder4",
          id: 4,
          child: [
            { title: "folder4", id: 7, child: "" },
            { title: "folder6", id: 8, child: "" },
            { title: "folder5", id: 9, child: "" }
          ]
        },
        { title: "folder10", id: 10, child: "" },
        { title: "folder11", id: 11, child: "" }
      ]
    },
    { title: "folder3", id: 2, child: "" },
    { title: "folder1", id: 3, child: "" }
  ]);
```

and i only wanted to change the property of child in folder5 how could i do it

Comment: Is this structure definitive? is this the case just for the first element in the array? Also there are two folder5 are you changing both of them?

Comment: The structure is not definitive i want to change value of deep most child with out effecting others

Answer (score 0):

In react if your state is an array and you want to update state mutating the existing array will not lead to rerender.

i.e.

```js
const [names,setNames] = useState(["sreedhar","reddy"]);

//This does not create a rerender
names.push("ac");
setNames(names);
```

Because when you mutate an array the reference of names does not change. React uses `Object.is()` to compare. And hence react thinks its not the new state.

The correct way is to pass a new array. Like

```js
const [names,setNames] = useState(["sreedhar","reddy"]);

setNames([...names,"ac"]);
```

To create a new array you can use spread operator or map.